# Usb Wifi adapter stopped working after forceful shutdown

Tags: drivers, wireless, modprobe, tp-link

I have a tl-wn722n. I installed the driver 8188eu using dkms and then ran it with modprobe the first time after installing ubuntu 16.04 and it was working. Now after a forceful shut down (through the power button), the wifi isn't working. I tried to run `sudo modprobe 8188eu` but I am getting `modprobe:ERROR: could not insert '8188eu8': Exec format error`. How can I fix this?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by uninstalling 8188eu driver by dkms and removing it from the kernel source tree , then adding it and installing it again. Probabbly it got corrupted due to the forceful shutdown.

Answer (score 0):

If you used https://github.com/lwfinger/rtl8188eu to make the driver you need to edit the dkms.conf file or you will have issues after every kernel update.

```
sudo -H gedit /usr/src/8188eu-1.0/dkms.conf
```

Make it look like

```
PACKAGE_NAME="8188eu"
PACKAGE_VERSION="1.0"
BUILT_MODULE_NAME="8188eu"
DEST_MODULE_LOCATION="/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/"
REMAKE_INITRD="yes"
AUTOINSTALL="yes"
MAKE="'make' all KVER=${kernelver}"
CLEAN="'make' clean"
```

Save and exit.  The original dkms.conf has another MAKE line after `MAKE="'make' all KVER=${kernelver}"` that messes up the kernel versioning and that is why you got the "Exec Format Error"